# Combination of positive integers in terms of primes (sophisticated version 2)

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Here comes a second sophisticated version of my conjecture, as critics came up the [first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407812/conjecture-on-combinate-of-positive-integers-in-terms-of-primes) was trivial.

Teorem [2](https://oeis.org/A226233)

for a given prime $p$ and a given power $m$ the representation of any positive integer $n\in \Bbb N$ in the form:
$$ n=(a_u p - b_u) \; p^m$$
is *unique* with the coefficient pairs (OEIS: [A226233](https://oeis.org/A226233), [A226236](https://oeis.org/A226236))
$$ \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \langle a_u \rangle=1+\left\lfloor\frac{u-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor=\frac{(p-1)+u-1-((u-1)mod(p-1))}{p-1}\\
    \langle b_u \rangle=u-(p-1)\left\lfloor\frac{u-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor=1+((u-1)mod(p-1))
  \end{array} \right.$$

while $a_u,b_u,u\in \Bbb N$ and $m\in \Bbb N_0$.

Can anyone help raising the proof? Or connect to another existing unsolved conjecture?

Note: $\lfloor\cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

[2](https://oeis.org/A226233): Theorem to be cited Vaseghi 2013

Comment: In order to make the statement stand some chance of being true, you might need to rephrase it so that it says that the representation is *unique for a given prime $p$*. Otherwise, the number 10 is a counter-example (it has one representation with $p=2$ and one with $p=5$).

Comment: thanks for helping fine tuning the formulation.

Comment: What makes you think this is true?  Where do the formulas for $a_u,b_u come from?

Comment: @PT No counter example.

Comment: Are you saying that $n$ and $p$ are given, and that then the claim is that there exist unique $m, u$ such that, when you calculate $a_u$,$b_u$ with those formulas the equation holds? Something about the way you phrase it leaves doubts in my mind, because I initially thought that you are claiming that those formulas are consequences of the equations, when we can choose $a_u,b_u$ freely.

Comment: I try it in your tune: $p$ and $m$ are given, and claim that there exists only one $u$ such that when we calculate $a_u$, $b_u$, with the sequences' formulas the equation holds for $n$. For every $n$ only one $u$!

Comment: Hmm. But don't you always have $b_u\in\{1,2,\ldots,p-2\}$? Therefore $a_up-b_u$ is never divisible by $p$. So $p^m$ has to be the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$. Therefore when $n$ and $p$ are known, $m$ is also known (and not a variable that we can choose freely).

Comment: It may be that we are miscommunicating. What I am say is, for example, that when $n=8, p=2, m=2$, the equation does not hold for any $u$, because $(a_up-b_u)p^m$ will always be divisible by $4$ but never by $8$, irrespective of the value of $u$.

Comment: Yes. You can decide to vary $m$ or $n$, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: 1. What do the angle brackets on $a_u,b_u$ mean? 2. It sounds like $m$ can be chosen to be anything, but if $p^m$ is not a divisor of $n$ there is no chance for the existence of a solution $u$, let a lone uniqueness. So did you mean for $m$ to be freely chosen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, the claim can be seen to be correct as follows.

The definition of the integer $b_u$ tells us that $b_u$ is the unique integer in the range $1\le b_u\le p-1$ that is congruent to $u$ modulo $p-1$. So choosing $u$ from the correct residue class modulo $p-1$ allows us to choose $b$ to be anything we wish in that range.

On the other hand, if $u\le p-1$, then $a_u=1$. But also if we replace $u$ with
$u'=u+k(p-1)$ we replace $a_u$ with $a_u+k$. As we saw in the preceding paragraph, $u$ and $u'$ give rise to the same value of $b_u$. All this means that a choice of $u$ allows us to assign the parameter $a_u$ to be any positive integer that we wish, and to assign the parameter $b_u$ any integer in the range $1\le b_u\le p-1$. The mapping $u\mapsto (a_u,b_u)$ is clearly a bijection from
$\mathbb{Z}_+$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+\times \{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$.

The claim follows from this. We are given the values of $n$ and $p$. As the factor $a_up-b_u$ is never divisible by $p$, we are forced to select $m$ in such a way that $p^m$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $m$. So we write
$$
n=n'p^m,
$$
where $n'$ is not a multiple of $p$. This determines $n'$ and $m$ uniquely.
Then as $n'$ is not a multiple of $p$, there exists a unique integer $r$ in the range
$1\le r \le p-1$ such that $n'+r$ is a multiple of $p$. So $n'+r=\ell p$ for some
positive integer $\ell$. Now the previous paragraph says that there exists a unique $u$ such that $a_u=\ell$ and $b_u=r$. Clearly $a_up-b_u=\ell p-r=n'$ and the claimed equation then holds. No freedom remains in the choice of $u$.

Illustrating this with an example $p=3$. I table some values of $a_u,b_u,a_up-b_u$ as functions of $u$
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
u&a_u&b_u&a_up-b_u\\
\hline
1&1&1&2\\
2&1&2&1\\
3&2&1&5\\
4&2&2&4\\
5&3&1&8\\
6&3&2&7\\
7&4&1&11\\
8&4&2&10
\end{array}
$$
It is clear that the last column will contain all the positive integers that are not multiples of $p=3$. All such numbers appear exactly once.

So for example when $n=63=7\cdot9=7\cdot3^2$, we are forced to select $m=2$ and $u=6$ (see the table).

Comment: @JL excellent! Is there a possibility we get in contact together?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you subscript $a,b$ with $u$ or where $u$ comes from.  If you say $p^m$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$ this is essentially the Euclidean division algorithm. $b_u$ is the remainder term, here in the range $[1,p-1]$.  Since you do not say $p^m$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $n$, we can decrement $m$ by $1$ and multiply $a_u, b_u$ by $p$ and get another representation.

Comment: $u$ is indexing the sequences $a_u$ and $b_u$, hence the conjecture includes $a_u$ and $b_u$ as the only set of natural number combinations for which this holds.So in this (other) representation $a_u$ and $b_u$ are part of the uniquness property: You can not apply other coefficeint combinations from whereever.

Comment: ... To emphasise, the conjecture does not say $p^m$ is the highest power, instead it proposes a unique (non-linear) combination with fixed set of coeffeicients.