# Ring of the residual classes $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$? $p$-adic integer?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

In a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407890/combination-of-positive-integers-in-terms-of-primes-sophisticated-version-2) we raised the theorem:

for a given prime $p$ and a given power $m$ the representation of any positive integer $n\in \Bbb N$ in the form:
$$ n=(a_u p - b_u) \; p^m$$
is *unique* with the coefficient pairs (OEIS: [A226233](https://oeis.org/A226233) [A226236](https://oeis.org/A226236))
$$ \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \langle a_u \rangle=1+\left\lfloor\frac{u-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor=\frac{(p-1)+u-1-((u-1)mod(p-1))}{p-1}\\
    \langle b_u \rangle=u-(p-1)\left\lfloor\frac{u-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor=1+((u-1)mod(p-1))
  \end{array} \right.$$

while $a_u,b_u,u\in \Bbb N$ and $m\in \Bbb N_0$.

Example: $b_u(p=5)={1,2,3,4}$

**The questions are:**

**1.** Is it mathematically correct to state that the sequence $b_u$ represents the ring of the residual classes $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$?

**2.** Is it correct to state that $b_u$ represents the coefficients $\alpha_i$ of corresponding  $p$-adic integers according the [common general description](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicInteger.html) $\sum_{k=q}^\infty \alpha_i p^k$?

**3.** How may one interpret $n=(a_u p - b_u) \; p^m$ then through the description $\sum_{k=q}^\infty \alpha_i p^k$?